# Qt Adding children to a QGraphicsItem derivate in a QGraphicsScene do not show up

Tags: c++, qt

I subclassed QGraphicsItem twice: 
*RingCollection* is a kind of container item that should be filled with a list of child items of type *RingCollectionItem*. To achieve this, there is a populate() method, that (for testing) simply generates one item and sets its parent to the current collection.

Now, when I add the item to the collection inside the populate method, it does not show up in the scene.
When I add it directly , it's there. I'm quite puzzled (and frankly, reaching this minimal test case took me ages, cause I had no idea where to look for the problem...)
So here it goes:

Code in main (extract):

```
// works, both collection and item are drawn
RingCollection collection(QPoint(0,0),150);
RingCollectionItem newitem;
newitem.setParentItem(&collection);
newitem.setPos(10.0, 10.0);

scene.addItem(&collection);
```

The other method:

```
//does not work: only the collection is drawn
RingCollection collection(QPoint(0,0),150);
collection.populate();

scene.addItem(&collection);
```

and the *void populate()* method:

```
RingCollectionItem newitem;
newitem.setParentItem(this);
newitem.setPos(10.0, 10.0);
```

Maybe anyone can see what I'm missing, as far as I can tell both does basically the same thing. My best guess is that passing *this* somehow doesn't do what I expect it to, although I've seen examples do this... (In my understanding, *this* is a pointer to the current instance, please correct me if I got this wrong).

Cheers, Louise

PS: I tested that populate actually gets called, just in case. It does ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to allocate your item on the heap so that it still exists after the function `populate()` returns

```
RingCollectionItem *newitem = new RingCollectionItem(this);
...
```